# Python & TkInter - How to get value from user in Entry Field then print it on terminal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning Python & Tkinter and following a tutorial. I'm making a program to do what I'm used to do in scripting languages such as Powershell, get a user value, and then do something with it, for starter.

I can't find any example code that looks like mine. So I'm asking for your help.

Basically, this program creates a frame with a Quit Button, an Entry widget where the user enters a value, & a OK button. Then, he presses the OK button, and the value should be printed in the python terminal.

I'm getting an error but I don't understand why. I'm following a tutorial so I'm doing it the way they show, by defining a class to create the frame, putting the buttons & text box inside it.

The function to get the user input text from the entry widget is set below, where I would put my other functions, if let's say, I would like to add functions for buttons to do a print. I managed to make the print work if the value to print is set before, but I can't get the value from the Entry Widget.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("Get a value and print it")
    self.info = Label(master, text="Please write something then click ENTER")
    self.info.pack()

    self.ebox= Entry()
    self.ebox.pack()

    self.viewnumber = Button(master, text="OK", activebackground="red", command=get_int)
    self.viewnumber.pack()

    self.quit = Button(master, text="Quit", activebackground="blue", command=quit)
    self.quit.pack()

def get_int():
    intnum = ebox.get
    print(intnum)

def quit():
    root.quit()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
my_gui = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkint
er\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\pyth222184.py", line 20, in get_int
    intnum = ebox.get
NameError: name 'ebox' is not defined
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, it's telling you that `ebox` doesn't exist. When I look through your code I have to agree: there's no `ebox`. There's a `self.ebox`, but `self.ebox` isn't the same as `ebox`. A good rule of thumb when debugging is to assume the error is telling the literal truth.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem is that ebox can't be accessed from the function. You need to use `self.ebox`, so that it actually references the instance variable `ebox`.
To see more about that, visit [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Also, you are using `self.ebox.get` instead of `self.ebox.get()`. `self.ebox.get` on its own would return the raw function object of `self.entry.get`. To actually call the function and get the contents, use `self.ebox.get()`.

But in order for that to work, `self` has to be defined. To do this, add self as the first argument in every method. When you call `instance.method()` Python will automatically pass `instance` in as `self`. Essentially, self lets you access the current instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your answer.

As you have suggested, I made this change:

`def get_int():
 intnum = self.ebox.get()
 print(intnum)`
And then I get this error:
`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

I'm pretty sure self is defined above... How is self not defined?

Comment: @Smor You need to put self in as an argument `get_int`, like what you did for `__init__`. When you call `object.method()` there is actually an argument for `method` called `self` that Python automatically passes in `object` as the value for.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman get_int is not a method, otherwise the initialization for the button would have `command = self.get_int` and the error would be `TypeError: get_int() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` so either the OP needs to use `my_gui` instead of `self` or make `get_int` a method which would make more sense anyway.

Comment: If I am understanding this problem correctly, those functions are all supposed to be within the class (ignoring indentation problems). Am I incorrect? Because if they are within the class then they are methods of the class.

Comment: @Smor We need some clarification from the OP on this.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. The get_int in Class is a method, and you can not call that like a function. You'd have to call that like a method something like this

```
elf.viewnumber = Button(master, text="OK",bg="red",command=lambda:my_gui.get_int() )
self.viewnumber.pack()
```

This is an example of code that would work.